# PHP- associative array (structure)

Tags: php, arrays, associative

Could anyone explain how does structure of that array look like?

```
$result['results'][0]['geometry']['location']
```

Comment: That should be easy to check me thinks

Comment: values are accessed using keys, here results,0,geometry,location are keys.

Comment: `<pre>` will format code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is

```
$result = array(
   'results'=> array(
      array(
         'geometry' => array(
            'location' => 'SOME VALUE'
         )
      )
   )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `var_dump` and / or `print_r` to view the structure of an array.

```
<?php
    $result['results'][0]['geometry']['location'] = 1;
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($result);
    print_r($result);
    echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Outputs

```
array(1) {
  ["results"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
      ["geometry"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["location"]=>
        int(1)
      }
    }
  }
}

Array
(
    [results] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [geometry] => Array
                        (
                            [location] => 1
                        )
                )
        )
)
```